# SQL LIKE only one letter

Tags: sql, sql-like

When i use LIKE statement in my SQL,

for example,

```
      SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "%k"
```

It will return all rows, where name ends on k.

It can return : Ok, OOk, OOOk,

How i can do same statement but with one letter, so it returns only Ok.

Or 2 letters, so it returns only OOk?

Answer (score 9):

`_` is a single character wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = `_k`
```

See this [IBM Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc/doc/wildcard.characters.using.sql.wildcards.html)

Comment: Yes, thats what i actually need! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use the equality operator (=) or the IN operator instead of the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('Ok', 'OOk')
```

Comment: There are more rows, i dont need only two. I need sql which select the  rows ending on 'k' and having length 2 characters

Comment: In that case, use `WHERE name LIKE '%k' AND LEN(name) = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `_` wildcard. It matches only a single character.

`_k` for Ok.
`__k` for Ook

Answer (score 0):

depending on the length you provide

For 1 character 'X' followed by k

```
Select * 
from table 
where length(name) = 2 
AND name = "%k"
```

For 2 character 'X' followed by k

```
Select * 
from table 
where length(name) = 3
AND name = "%k"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an underscore (`_`) character. See the documentation about [operator LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

So, the query you need (1 or 2 chars before `k`) is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '_k' OR name LIKE '__k'
```